# How to perform a "select" on an array in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, loops

I have an array in objective c whose contents are this:

```
 reg_nr = 0002,          valor = 00010,       nomtech  =  ab-dd 
 reg_nr = 0002,          valor = 00020,       nomtech  =  ab-dt 
 reg_nr = 0003,          valor = 00030,       nomtech  =  ab-ds 
 reg_nr = 0003,          valor = 00040,       nomtech  =  ab-jh
```

I want to get a value out of this array just like a select statement.

e.g if this were a select statement which column names

```
reg_nr   valor   nomtech
0002     00010   ab-dd
0002     00020   ab-dt
0003     00030   ab-ds
0003     00040   ab-jh
```

The select query would be `select nomtech from tablename where valor = '00030'` and I would get the value `ab-ds`.

How do I do this for the array above?

Edit - Clarification - this is show the array is formed -

```
SUPObjectList *docs2 = [MMRDS_QSSCabeceraPedido findAll];

// findall is a sap command that returns a list of objects 

    if ([docs2 length] > 0)
    {

        for (MMRDS_QSSCabeceraPedido * oneRec in docs2)
        {
            [array1 addObject:oneRec];

        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the type of your array's objects?

Comment: The contents are `NSString` objects, right?

Comment: yes the objects in array are NSString

Comment: There's your first problem.  Make each line into a custom object and that will both solve this issue and many future issues.  Always use the correct data type.

Comment: You should use a regular expression, or you can simply split your array by ' ' and take just those cells which have 00030 on the second part of the split

Comment: @silverkid is your string object like that: NSString *str = @"reg_nr = 0002,          valor = 00010,       nomtech  =  ab-dd " ?

Comment: does the Edit i made makes things clear ? or should i give more info ? @Greg yes each row one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSPredictate like that:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@", @"valor = 00030"];
    NSArray *filterArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"ARRAY: %@", filterArray);
```

I gives you whole object, if you want to get just nom tech you can get the string object from the filtered array and you can spoilt it by ','

```
NSArray *splitArray = [filterArray[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now in you can get your nom tech by call

```
NSString *string = splitArray[2];
```

This string will contain `nomtech  =  ab-dd` so you have to remove the substring you don't need.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [NSPredicate](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) , it is very similar to 'select' statement to filter an array